# RestTemplate postForObject method to return List<String>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I trying to call a rest API which used to return the data as below,

```
List<MyObject> myObj;
String result;
String failures response;
```

At the consumer end how can I get the `List<String>` in response for the `List<MyObj>`
When I used the `restTemplate.postForObject(url,request,MyString.class).getMyString()` method.

and MyString class has the following properties,

```
List<String> myString;
```

Any Help must be appreciated.

Comment: Something is messed up here. You get `MyString` object as a response from your endpoint. You want to get `List<String>` from it? So call `myString.getMyString();` But what about `List<MyObj>`? Is it one of the request params?

Comment: List<MyObj> is not part of request. And the response is something like { "myObj":[{..},{}]

Comment: Update your question with the endpoint